# How to write $e^{2iz}$ in the form $u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I took an exam on Complex Analysis recently, and questions involving the complex logarithm and exponential were a sticking point for me. Questions such as:

Q. The function $f$ is defined by $f(z) = e^{2iz}$. Write $f(z)$ in the form: $$f(z) = f(x+iy) = u(x, y) +iv(x, y)$$

I know that the complex exponential is defined by $e^{z} = e^{x}(\cos(y)+i\sin(y))$ and then I think you'd just expand this and take the real and imaginary parts for $u(x,y)$ and $v(x, y)$  but I'm not sure on how to deal with the $2i$ part in $f(z)$.

Any help on where to go from here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $e^z=e^{2i(x+iy)} = e^{-2y} \cdot e^{i \cdot 2x}$

Answer (score 1):

Considering $z=a+ib$, $$e^{2iz}=e^{-2b}e^{2ia}$$

So your function would be:

$$f(a+ib)=e^{-2b}(cos(2a)+i sin(2a))$$

$$u(a,b)=e^{-2b}cos(2a)$$

$$v(a,b)= e^{-2b}sin(2a)$$